# Envers with Hibernate Interceptors, onDelete

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm trying to implement a simple Envers + interceptor based approach to audit my Hibernate entities. For this, as per the typical approach, there's a `BaseEntity` with all the audit properties:

```
BaseEntity{
    createdOn;
    createdBy;
    updatedOn;
    updatedBy;
}
```

In the `AuditInterceptor`, I have overridden `onFlushDirty` and `onSave` methods to manipulate the above properties depending upon whether it's an entity Save or Update. Everything works as expected for Save and Update.

The issue that I'm facing is: I need a way to be able to manipulate the above properties for Delete operations as well. Overriding `onDelete` does give me a handle to the `state[]` array, but modifying it doesn't reflect in the _AUD (audit) tables. In a nutshell: I want to be able to audit delete operations in the audit tables as well.

Is there a workaround for this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to implement the onSave, onFlushDirty methods.

You just need to implement the RevisionListener interface. If you follow the pattern here you don't need to add those properties (createdOn etc) to your entities either (unless you need them for normal operations).

See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/envers/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#revisionlog for more details. In the example here they are using Seam to get the logged in user.

Envers allow you to separate your auditing from your entities which keeps your normal model clean and minimises the code required to do the auditing.

Comment: Wow. When I first looked at your answer I thought this guy missed the point. But turns out, I was missing the point all along. Thanks a lot!